# Can you measure a motor torque using a load cell connected to the stator? how?

Tags: electromagnetism

I saw a picture here: https://measurementsensors.honeywell.com/techresources/appnotes/Pages/Ways_to_Measure_the_Force_Acting_on_a_Rotating_Shaft.aspx

[image]

It shows a motor casing connected to a load cell. I don't understand how it transmits the torque from the shaft to the load cell.

Comment: Question is not clear. Please make a diagram if you cannot elaborate more on your concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only considering steady state torque with accuracy, then yes. Newton's third law applies and so any torque seen by the motor shafts and armature sees a reaction torque on the motor frame, attached to the stator.

But during transient acceleration there are losses not necessarily seen in transient torque. These losses can however be estimated using a model of the motor and voltage and current measures.

Comment: But if during these transients are seen variations of torque, it may be that these variations are not captured correctly?

Comment: @user3545440 Yes - the motor 'system' has various means to 'store' energy during a transient so what instantaneously appears at the shaft may not necessarily be reflected where the stator is mounted. But modeling and estimation can be used to 'fill-in' these transient gaps if it is necessary to do that.

Comment: can anybody suggest how a modelling or a estimation of this effect can be done?

Comment: @user3545440 look at books, journals, conference papers in Automatic Control Systems - particularly motor control systems, sensorless motor controls. IEEE, American Control Conference, Conference on Decision and Control, etc. You can also probably access allot on line.

Comment: Can somebody help me with this problem? I searched and I didn't found something useful. I'm not an electrical guy.

Comment: @user3545440 What is your specific situation? If you are using a newly purchased motor, the manufacturer will typically have technical support staff and often white papers on how to connect/test their motors. If not you will need to learn on your own or hire a contractor. The details of how to connect/interface are way outside the scope of this physics forum. Try Engineering.